# EXCEL - Moving a multiline address in a cell to multiple cells for a set of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have hundreds of postal addresses formatted into single cells and I want to take each line of the address and have it put into its own cell in the row so that street address, city, post/zipcode etc all sit in the own cell for the purposes of doing a mail merge. I can't seem to get it to work using Text to Column as the multiline seems to be interfering with this. Are there any work-arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TEXTSPLIT()` function. The first parameter is your address, and the second parameter is a line break. To insert the line break in the formula, you need to press `ALT`+`ENTER`.

`TESTSPLIT` alone will create an array formula, and create as many adjacent cells as there are line breaks.

You can access an individual line by its number by adding an `INDEX`, as shown below:

[image]

You can also merge all the elements back into one cell, with each element separated by a coma or any other character, by adding a `TEXTJOIN`:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! This has been immensely helpful exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)